# Scrapy & ASPX site - fails to pull pages beyond 11 - 302 errors

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to pull data from this site: https://inform.alabama.gov/employeesearch.aspx. The current query that I have below works up to and including page 11. I think the issue resides with the "__VIEWSTATE" form element. It doesn't appear to change with each request. It should represent the current response page in the loop so the server knows how to interpret the subsequent response. It seems to only render the value present on the first response, so I believe that the server is rejecting it because page 12 is not a valid pathway from pages 1-10. If you take a look at the pagination it goes from 1 to ..., where the ... renders page 11. When page 11 is rendered, it changes the pagination to: 11 to ..., where the ... renders page 21.

Note that num_pages defines the total page count. Currently set to 15, it processes pages 1-11 and returns 302 errors for the other pages.

How should this be modified to yield the results for all 661 pages?

```py
from scrapy import FormRequest, Spider
from scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror import HttpError
from twisted.internet.error import DNSLookupError
from twisted.internet.error import TimeoutError, TCPTimedOutError


class EmployeesSpider(Spider):
    name = 'employees'
    start_urls = ['https://inform.alabama.gov/employeesearch.aspx']
    num_pages = 15  # 661
    name_excludes = ['', ' ', '1']

    def parse(self, response):
        formdata = self.get_formdata(response, 0)
        formdata['__EVENTTARGET'] = 'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btn_Search'
        formdata['__EVENTARGUMENT'] = ''
        yield FormRequest(
            url='https://inform.alabama.gov/employeesearch.aspx',
            method="POST",
            dont_filter=True,
            formdata=formdata,
            callback=self.perform_search,
            errback=self.failure)

    def perform_search(self, response):
        for employee in response.xpath('//*[@id="ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1"]//tr'):
            emp_name = employee.xpath('.//td[1]//text()').get()
            if emp_name is not None and emp_name not in self.name_excludes:
                final_name = emp_name.strip()
                yield {
                    'name': final_name,
                    'email': employee.xpath('.//td[1]//span//a//text()').get(),
                    'org': employee.xpath('.//td[2]//text()').get(),
                    'phone': employee.xpath('.//td[3]//span//a//text()').get(),
                }

        # Download search pages starting from #2
        for i in range(2, self.num_pages):
            formdata = self.get_formdata(response, i)
            yield FormRequest(
                url='https://inform.alabama.gov/employeesearch.aspx',
                method="POST",
                dont_filter=True,
                formdata=formdata,
                callback=self.parse_results,
                errback=self.failure)

    def get_formdata(self, response, page_num):
        eventargument = 'Page$' + str(page_num)

        viewstate = response.css(
            'input#__VIEWSTATE::attr(value)').get()
        if viewstate is None:
            viewstate = ''

        viewstategen = response.css(
            'input#__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR::attr(value)').get()
        if viewstategen is None:
            viewstategen = ''

        eventvalidation = response.css(
            'input#__EVENTVALIDATION::attr(value)').get()
        if eventvalidation is None:
            eventvalidation = ''

        formdata = {
            '__EVENTTARGET': 'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$GridView1',
            '__EVENTARGUMENT': eventargument,
            '__VIEWSTATE': viewstate,
            '__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR': viewstategen,
            '__EVENTVALIDATION': eventvalidation,
            'ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24txt_FirstName': '',
            'ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24txt_LastName': '',
            'ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24ddl_Agency': 'Not+Selected',
            'ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24txt_Phone': '',
        }
        return formdata

    def parse_results(self, response):
        for employee in response.xpath('//*[@id="ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1"]//tr'):
            emp_name = employee.xpath('.//td[1]//text()').get()
            if emp_name is not None and emp_name not in self.name_excludes:
                final_name = emp_name.strip()
                yield {
                    'name': final_name,
                    'email': employee.xpath('.//td[1]//span//a//text()').get(),
                    'org': employee.xpath('.//td[2]//text()').get(),
                    'phone': employee.xpath('.//td[3]//span//a//text()').get(),
                }

    def failure(self, failure):
        # log all failures
        self.logger.error(repr(failure))

        # in case you want to do something special for some errors,
        # you may need the failure's type:

        if failure.check(HttpError):
            # these exceptions come from HttpError spider middleware
            # you can get the non-200 response
            response = failure.value.response
            self.logger.error('HttpError on %s', response.url)

        elif failure.check(DNSLookupError):
            # this is the original request
            request = failure.request
            self.logger.error('DNSLookupError on %s', request.url)

        elif failure.check(TimeoutError, TCPTimedOutError):
            request = failure.request
            self.logger.error('TimeoutError on %s', request.url)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to get the total number of pages.
Press Search, go to the last page and, save 661 to `num_pages`.

Start from the beginning, now knowing how many pages do you have:

```
from scrapy import FormRequest, Spider


class EmployeesSpider(Spider):
    name = 'employees'
    start_urls = ['https://inform.alabama.gov/employeesearch.aspx']
    num_pages = None
    name_excludes = ['', ' ', '1', None]

    def parse(self, response):
        yield FormRequest.from_response(
            response,
            dont_filter=True,
            formdata={
                '__EVENTTARGET': 'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btn_Search',
                '__EVENTARGUMENT': ''
            },
            callback=self.perform_search
        )

    def perform_search(self, response):
        if not self.num_pages:
            # first get the total number of pages
            yield FormRequest.from_response(
                response,
                dont_filter=True,
                formdata={
                    '__EVENTTARGET': 'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$GridView1',
                    '__EVENTARGUMENT': 'Page$Last'
                },
                callback=self.parse_total_pages
            )
        else:
            for employee in response.xpath(
                '//table[@id="ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView1"]//'
                'tr[position() < last()]'
            ):
                emp_name = employee.xpath('.//td[1]//text()').get()
                if emp_name not in self.name_excludes:
                    final_name = emp_name.strip()
                    yield {
                        'name': final_name,
                        'email': employee.xpath('.//td[1]//span//a//text()').get(),
                        'org': employee.xpath('.//td[2]//text()').get(),
                        'phone': employee.xpath('.//td[3]//span//a//text()').get(),
                    }

            # go to the next page
            current_page = response.xpath(
                '//tr[@class="employeeSearchPagerStye"]/td//span/text()'
            ).get()
            current_page = int(current_page)
            if current_page < self.num_pages:
                yield FormRequest.from_response(
                    response,
                    dont_filter=True,
                    formdata={
                        '__EVENTTARGET': 'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$GridView1',
                        '__EVENTARGUMENT': f'Page${current_page + 1}'
                    },
                    callback=self.perform_search
                )

    def parse_total_pages(self, response):
        total_pages = response.xpath(
            '//tr[@class="employeeSearchPagerStye"]/td//span/text()'
        ).get()
        self.num_pages = int(total_pages)

        # back to search
        yield FormRequest.from_response(
            response,
            dont_filter=True,
            formdata={
                '__EVENTTARGET': 'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btn_Search',
                '__EVENTARGUMENT': ''
            },
            callback=self.perform_search
        )
```